# How to pass textbox value to controller in mvc4

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

How to pass the value on this textbox to controler.

In Index.cshtml file

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
</head>
<body>
    <form>
        <input type="text" id="test" name="test" />
        <input type="submit" value="Click" />
    </form>
</body>
```

In MyHomeControler file

```
public ActionResult Index(string test)
{
     string val = test;
     return View();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You're passing the value correctly.  However, your form isn't actually referring to the action.  (Or any action.)  You can do it manually:

```
<form action="/MyHome/Index">
```

or, ideally, use the HTML helpers:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "MyHome"))
{
    <input type="text" id="test" name="test" />
    <input type="submit" value="Click" />
}
```

Using the HTML helpers lets the framework decide the correct path to the action, in case it's routed differently.

Answer (score 2):

> First you need to button type **"submit"**. so your form values will be
>   submitted to your Action method.

```
<input type="submit" value="submit" />
```

> Second you need to add your model as parameter in your Action method.

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult MyDemoForm(FormModel modelObj)
    {
       var strFname=modelObj.FirstName;
             return View();
    }
```

> Third, If your Controller name is **"MyFormController"**. you need to
>   change the parameter of your Html.Beginform in your view to this:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("MyDemoForm", "MyForm", FormMethod.Post))
    {
    //your fields
    }
```

If your view is the same name as your Action method which is **"MyDemoForm"** you don't need to add any parameter in the Html.BeginForm. just to make it simple. like so:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
//your fields
}
```